# Laravel 9 Inline Blade Template Rendering; Rendering constant instead of variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

There is a new feature in Laravel 9 that allows inline blade template rending. Link: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#rendering-inline-blade-templates

Let’s say I have a value stored in the database  (as the body of the email) I want to render from database as email.

E.g
`<p> Dear {{$first_name}} {{$last_name}} </p>`

I would use this;

`Blade::render($body, [‘first_name’ => $first_name, ‘last_name’ => $last_name]);`

With this I’m able to output something like;

`Dear John Doe`

In the body of the email sent.

However, what if I want to use
`<p> Dear {{first_name}} {{last_name}} </p>`

in my email template stored in the database (without the dollar sign, making it a constant rather than a variable). How can I render this constant using the Blade::render()?

Comment: You most likely can't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Blade template view as a raw HTML string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938285/how-to-get-blade-template-view-as-a-raw-html-string)

Comment: Besides, "Class constants MUST be declared in all upper case with underscore separators".

Comment: you would have to define those constants before calling `render` as `{{ ... }}` is replaced with `<?php echo e(...); ?>` and then that is evaluated

Comment: Why is this even relevant? Thinking there is another solution about the reasoning to avoiding the $first_name approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to manipulate the templates, before sending output to blade.

Laravel has many helpers to do things like that.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
 
$string = '{{first_name}} {{last_name}}';
 
$replaced = Str::replace('{{', '{{$', $string);

// in $replaced you'll have '{{$first_name}} {{$last_name}}'
```

Above code will do the job.